# using map to bind this fails in reactjs component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very confused as to why I cannot set the state correctly when executing map. Any advice on how to set the binding correctly without building a specific function for setting state?

```
export default class Marker extends Component {


constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {events:''};
}
    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("/json/meetup.json").then((response) =>{
            return response;
        }).then((json) => {
            this.setState({events: json});
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })

    };

render() {
   var finally1 = this.state.events.results.map((result) => {
        if (result.venue) {
            <img lat={result.venue.lat} lng={result.venue.lon} src='images/32/flat_Golf.png'/>
        }
    }, this);
    return (
    {finally1}
)};

};
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need this in an fat arrow function 
also add a return statement

```
render() {
   var finally1 = this.state.events.map((result) => {
        if (result.venue) {
            return (<img lat={result.venue.lat} lng={result.venue.lon} src='images/32/flat_Golf.png'/>)
        }
    });
    return (
    <div>
     {finally1}
    </div>
)};
```

Comment: checking it plxz wait

Comment: plz tell me what the exact issue u are facing , render function now looks fine to me.

Comment: plz check now i have omitted the results , u were using event.results.
results were not used while updating state